# Add data to begining of FlatList without changing position

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to implement an "onBeginReached" like props in flatlist. I would like to append some data at the begining of my data array in a transparent way to user.

So using this flatList :

```
const App = () => {
  const flatListRef = useRef(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState(generateData(20));

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  console.log(item);
  return (
    <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

  const handleMomentumScroll = (event) => {
    console.log("Momentum end")
    const xOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
    const index = Math.round(xOffset / 30);

    if (index < 1) {
      setData([-10 ,-9, -8, -7, -6,-5, -3, -2, -1, ...data]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      style={{ width: 200, alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 150 }}
      initialScrollIndex={10}
      horizontal
      data={data}
      snapToAlignment={'start'}
      decelerationRate={'fast'}
      snapToInterval={30}
      getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
         length: 30,
         offset: 30 * index,
         index,
      })}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      onMomentumScrollEnd={handleMomentumScroll}
    />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  itemContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    borderRadius: 15,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  itemText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```

(https://snack.expo.io/GUblotbZc)

If I scroll to the index 0, it'll unshift my new data to my data array. But, it'll scroll automatically to the first index of the new data array. I would like to keep the current position when unshifting new data to the array.

There is a way to impletement that behaviour ?

Answer (score 4):

here is demo: https://snack.expo.io/@nomi9995/flatlisttest

use `maintainVisibleContentPosition` [props](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#maintainvisiblecontentposition)  for preventing auto scroll in IOS but unfortunately, it's not working on android but good news is [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29055) has come for android and need to merge with react native.

```
<FlatList
  ref={(ref) => { this.chatFlatList = ref; }}
  style={styles.flatList}
  data={this.state.items}
  renderItem={this._renderItem}
  maintainVisibleContentPosition={{
     minIndexForVisible: 0,
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Using typescript, this props is not exported by react.

Comment: it is exporting https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/fa5d3fb6b8c561b749f3e86316d06543a52dcc1c/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js#L199 . which version of react-native you are using?

Comment: I'm using expo, so SDK-37 actually. It look like this props is exported for <ScrollView> but not <FlatList>. However, I need a cross platform solution, so for the moment, I can't use this.

Comment: @TotoNaBendo https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#props you can see we can use scrollview props in flatlist. this is a pure solution. other solution are with `onScroll` and `onContentSizeChange` but that are much laggy solution

Comment: for Android, you can patch react native by using this pull request https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/29466

Comment: I am getting the same error and even in IOS, it's not working. The flat list should not be a scroll when I am appending data on Top.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it is by inverting FlatList using the `inverted` prop, and also reversing my list. In this way, the top of FlatList will be at the bottom with last item in my array is visible there.
When user scrolls to the top `onEndReached` is triggered, and I add new items to the beginning of my array and they will be added to the top of FlatList with out changing the current visible item at the top.

Answer (score -1):

You can use to Flatlist prop named "ListHeaderComponent" to add any component at the beginning of your Flatlist. https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent